# Sort order algorithm for swagger endpoints

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I’m currently working with a Swagger-parser and making an application that parses swagger files and tries the given endpoints by sending HTTP-request and compares status code with the swagger-file.

And I have a problem with finding a proper algorithm that sorts the endpoints. For example, I want to ensure that POST-requests that create an object get handled before an endpoints that require id parameter from the prior POST-requests.

Below swagger-file is in right order, but it will be files that are not ordered and it’s then I need some sort of algorithm..

```
"paths": {
"/pets": {
  "post": {
    "summary": "Create a pet",
    "operationId": "createPets",
    "tags": [
      "pets"
    ],
    "responses": {
      "201": {
        "description": "Null response"
      },
      "default": {
        "description": "unexpected error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"/pets/{petId}": {
  "get": {
    "summary": "Info for a specific pet",
    "operationId": "showPetById",
    "tags": [
      "pets"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "petId",
        "in": "path",
        "required": true,
        "description": "The id of the pet to retrieve",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Expected response to a valid request",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Pets"
        }
      },
      "default": {
        "description": "unexpected error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

So I happily take directions for either an algorithm or information about how to sort it.

Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting files like these are always pointless as the contents in the file are order agnostic.

Instead, a better way would be to parse the OpenAPI file to generate objects (aka models) which can then be used to run the operation you're referring to.

A good example is the [Swagger Parser - Java](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) that converts a given OpenAPI spec file into Java models which can then be used as per the use-case.

Refer [here](https://openapi.tools/#parsers) for a list of parse libraries specific to different languages

Comment: I’n not sure that i understand what you mean. I have a swagger-parser that generates objects but I’m not sure how to generate in the same objects when it’s different endpoints.

Comment: To clarify, If one endpoint contains ID as an URL-parameter, how would you know which endpoint to get that particular ID from before you start testing the endpoint with the ID?